# Any benefit in using Razz Berry and Great Ball at same time? Any harm?

Tags: pokemon-go

For new Pokemon, I throw a Razz Berry and use a Great Ball. That should yield a very high catch rate?

Yet, I am not sure I am gaining any benefit. In fact, with a Razz Berry + Great Ball combo, a few times the Pokemon have run away after I missed just the first and second throw. Normally, I can throw upwards of 6 regular balls before it runs away.

1. Are the higher catch rates of Razz Berries and Great Balls additive if used in combination?
2. Any chance that I am actually making it more difficult to catch Pokemon with this combination? If I start missing, they run away sooner?

Comment: I always thought Razz Berries increased the chances of catching them. Not the chances of them running away.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf My perception was that after throwing a Razz Berry, the catch chance goes up. BUT, if you miss that high chance throw, then every missed throw thereafter has a higher chance it will run away. So, throwing a Razz Berry had an element of danger. You had to nail the first throw. At least, that is what I sensed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes they are additive if used at the same time.
2. There is no data on if using a Pokeball and missing causes them to run away faster after a failed catch.

More often than not, the reason for the run away is just the higher the cp and more difficult a capture is, the higher chance of running away seems to be.

Comment: Missing a pokemon with any pokeball will not cause them to run away or make them more likely to run away

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Personal experience as well as no one has ever mentioned anything like missing causes a decrease in catch rate

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the effects are additive. This can be seen by tapping and holding on a Pokéball to see the color after throwing a razz berry, and then releasing it and switching to a great ball and doing the same thing. You will be able to see the difference in color of the ring change color (provided it wasn't green to start with).

source- personal experience

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using both a Razz Berry and a Great Ball (as well as an Ultra Ball when you get to level 20+), increases the chance of capture additively.

But you have to remember that a Razz Berry *only* counts for the next hit. You can miss the Pokemon and keep throwing, but once you hit, if they jump out of the ball, the effect of the Razz Berry has worn off. If you keep throwing Great Balls, you're then getting only the Great Ball multiplier (which I believe is 1.5x the chance of a normal Pokeball).

So the effect you're noticing could mean that after the Pokemon jumps out, you're not using another Razz Berry to keep the chances up.